# Using variables from host inventory with loop

Tags: ansible

> This is not a repeat of any question using previous versions of Ansible. The answers here are not with `loop`.

I have the following host inventory:

```
[workers]
worker-vm-0 private_ip=10.240.0.20
worker-vm-1 private_ip=10.240.0.21
worker-vm-2 private_ip=10.240.0.22
```

I want to access the `private_ip` variables when using a `loop`, for example:

```
- name: Loop through private_ip
  loop: "{{ groups['workers'] }}"
  shell: echo "{{ item }},{{ item['private_ip'] }}"
```

There's no problem with just the `{{ item }}` - that works as intended.

To get the variable I tried both `{{ item['private_ip'] }}` and `{{ item.private_ip }}` - I get undefined variable errors for both.

How can I access the variables of my host inventory when using the new-ish `loop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *hostvars*

```
- name: Loop through private_ip
  loop: "{{ groups['workers'] }}"
  debug: msg="{{ item }},{{ hostvars[item].private_ip }}"
```